# An intterupted thread still continue executing

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to understand the behavior of threads so I made that peace of code :

```
    public class Threads extends Thread {
        private Account account = new Account();
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Threads t = new Threads();
            t.start();
            t.interrupt();
        }
   @Override
    synchronized public void run() {
        System.out.println("Running...");
        account.func();account.func2();
    }

}
class Account {

    public synchronized void func()  {
        try {
            System.out.println("func");
            wait(1000);
            System.out.println("hi func");
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.println("Ex func");
        }
    }
    public synchronized void func2()  {
        try {
            System.out.println("func2");
           wait(2000);
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted());
            System.out.println("Hi func2");
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.println("Ex func2");
        }
    }
}
```

the output was :

*Running*

*func*

*Ex func*

*func2*

*false*

*Hi func2*

so I know that interrupting thread while waiting the lock object to be notified would throw `IntteruptedException` but what I'm trying to understand the thread is interrupted WHY func 2 is still be called normally without even an exception ?!!!!
and why `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` prints `false` even if the current thread is intterupted already

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you call

```
t.interrupt();
```

the `Thread` `t` is currently executing the `wait(1000)` call. This will cause an `InterruptedException` which you `catch`. After that, execution continues normally. The `func` method returns and the `func2` method is executed.

Also, read the javadoc of [`Thread#interrupt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29)

> If this thread is blocked in an invocation of the `wait()`, `wait(long)`,
>   or `wait(long, int)` methods of the `Object` class, or of the `join()`,
>   `join(long)`, `join(long, int)`, `sleep(long)`, or `sleep(long, int)`, methods
>   of this class, **then its interrupt status will be cleared and it will
>   receive an InterruptedException.**

Comment: but when ``func2()`` is executed the thread is already interrupted isn't that mean it will go into a Blocked state and won't able to execute ``func2()``?

Comment: @YouYou What makes you think it should be in a blocked state?

Comment: @YouYou It might be old, but check [this](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/examples/java-6-thread-state-machine-diagram-example.html) out and the official Java tutorial on [interrupts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html).

Comment: ok that is nice but won't ``interrupt()`` force the thread to terminate or finish run ? if yes then ``func2`` shouldn't be called if no so ``func2()`` should throw interrupted exception like ``func()`` that is the whole point?

Comment: @YouYou Read the javadoc and the linked articles again. `interrupt` doesn't terminate a thread. `An interrupt is an indication to a thread that it should stop what it is doing and do something else`. The javadoc states `then its interrupt status will be cleared and it will receive an InterruptedException.` Your `func()` will receive an `InterruptedException` and will catch it and handle it by printing `Ex func`.  There's no reason for an `InterruptedException` to happen in `func2()`.